# Color scales in conditional formatting based on criteria

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

For a given data set, say:

```
a            b    
6,424,194    658,380
10,297,799   11,176,812
503,857      293,825
10,674,361   328,429
3,329,746    3,060,234
8,851,635    15,009,888
```

I am trying to conditionally format b in two ways: 
for each row, 1) `if a-b<0 then color scale from minimum value in red to 0 in white`.
2) `if a-b>=0 then color scale from 0 in white to maximum value in green`.

I separately found it possible to color-scale formatting based on EITHER minimum value (red) to 0 OR 0 to maximum value (green), but not both. Separately, I can set conditional formatting based on condition (for example a-b>0), but then I can implement a color scale, only one color.

Anyway to do what I am trying to achieve?

This is an attempt at adding colors myself manually to show what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe share a screenshot with colors showing how the conditional formatting would look?

Comment: @BigBen updated!